# PostgreSQL - Generate unique name on insert based on other columns

Tags: postgresql

I have this table:

```
create table people (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar,
    surname varchar,
    uname varchar unique
);
```

I want to generate the value of uname on insert, based on name and surname values, appending a number if there is a duplicate, for example:

```
insert into people (name, surname) values ('John', 'Doe');
insert into people (name, surname) values ('John', 'Doe');
insert into people (name, surname) values ('Sarah', 'Doe');
insert into people (name, surname) values ('Sarah', 'Doe');
```

will produce

```
 id | name  | surname | uname 
----+-------+---------+----------
  1 | John  | Doe     | JohnDoe
  2 | John  | Doe     | JohnDoe1
  3 | Sarah | Doe     | SarahDoe
  4 | Sarah | Doe     | SarahDoe1
```

Is it possible to do it with PostgreSQL?

Comment: *Possible*, of course, but you would have to define how to deal with deletes and updates. More importantly: I would stick with `name` and `surname` in combination with the serial `id` and **drop** the redundant column `uname`, which adds nothing but pain.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I want to have an human readable identifier, that's the reason to use `uname`. If I stick with `name`, `surname` and `id`, and remove `uname`, I'll end up with an identifier like `JohnDoe519348`, which is not so readable.

Comment: I still wouldn't do it. The best solution (if you must) depends on the *exact* setup. In your definition both `name` and `surname` can be NULL, which doesn't make sense. Is white space allowed ('Sue Allen')? How to deal with it? Is `uname` supposed to be case-sensitive? Are digits allowed in `name` and `surname`? If not, add a `CHECK` constraint to disallow or it will break some day. Are rows updated or deleted? You'll end up with `JohnDoe7` and no other `JohnDoe`. Concurrent access and race conditions are a problem, too. This can go wrong in *many* ways. Simo's function is bound to break ...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with triggers and trigger procedures (trigger functions). Read [Tutorial on triggers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_triggers.htm) and from PostgreSQL documentation [40.9. Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html). The following is the code for both the procedure and the trigger (there might be even more elegant ways to form the procedure):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_people() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    DECLARE
    u_num integer;
    BEGIN
    u_num := (SELECT count(*) FROM people WHERE NEW.name = people.name AND NEW.surname = people.surname);
    NEW.uname := NEW.name || NEW.surname || CASE u_num WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE u_num::text END;
    RETURN NEW;
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER create_people BEFORE INSERT ON people
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_people();
```

*DISCLAIMER: As mentioned in the comments you should carefully plan on how to handle the possible deletes and updates on `uname` before using a solution based on this trigger on any production environment.*

Comment: As Erwin mentioned in comments to the question, this will break easily. Insert three John Does, remove the first, insert a fourth one. You have two JohnDoe2:s, unless the column has a unique constraint, in which case you can never insert a fourth John Doe unless you "fix" the others first.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment, added a disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

I have applied the following solution.

```
drop trigger if exists unique_username on users;
drop function if exists unique_username();
drop table if exists users;

create table users (
  id serial primary key,
  username varchar unique,
  name varchar not null,
  surname varchar not null,
  check (username is not null and username != '')
);

create or replace function unique_username() returns trigger as
$$
declare
  unique_username varchar;
  i integer;
begin
  unique_username := coalesce(new.username, LOWER(CONCAT(new.name, new.surname)));
  unique_username := TRANSLATE(unique_username, 'çğıöşü', 'cgiosu');
  new.username = unique_username;
  i := 1;
  while exists(select * from users where username = new.username) loop
    new.username = TRANSLATE(unique_username, 'çğıöşü', 'cgiosu') || i;
    i := i + 1;
  end loop;
  return new;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger unique_username
before insert on users
for each row execute procedure unique_username();

insert into users(name,surname) values ('mehmet','seven'), ('mehmet', 'seven');
insert into users(username, name, surname) values ('mehmetseven', 'mehmet', 'seven');
```

Comment: please ealborate what you have done, so that other can use that knowledge